Barrier for sharing keyboard and mouse between PCs is not working
Using barrier application for sharing keyboard and mouse, I can make a connection between the 2 computers.
However, when I want to change the screen, I can see in the logs that the mouse moved, however, I can't see it and the keyboard is not working. My PC (server) is win 10 and remote is win server 2012.
